# Session showing Object reference to null exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I have a VB.NET application which runs perfectly with local host. But when I upload it to my server the session objects throw null reference exception.

Sessions is not working in a single page. If I use session on any other page it is working perfectly.

I have enabled session in that page using the `EnableSessionState` property. Also in `web.config` I enabled the use of session variables.

The way I am using session is as follows:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("leftmenu").ToString()
```

I have also tried adding `System.Web` infront but it has not been fruitful.

Please suggest something useful.

Comment: At what point are you trying to access the session, is it posible you have accessed the session in the wrong place in the page lifecycle ? I think a little more code (page that works, page that doesn't) might be needed

Comment: Are either HttpContent.Current or HttpContent.Current.Session null?

Comment: In page load............And Session can take null values as per my understanding.....

Answer (score 0):

check if session variable is null before using it.

pseudo code

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session("leftmenu") is not null) 
    HttpContext.Current.Session("leftmenu").ToString()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be nothing rather than null, or maybe system.DBNull is accessing a databse. It doesn't address the underlying issue either

Comment: If HttpContext.Current.Session("leftmenu").ToString() = String.Empty Then
                HttpContext.Current.Session("Category") = Convert.ToInt32(splt(0))
                'HttpContext.Current.Session("Category") = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("catid"))
            End If................not working